# How to get an array of types from an array of objects?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have an object[] which I am using to dynamically invoke a method via reflection. Due to an AmbiguousMatchException I need to know the types, and it would be difficult to know them ahead of time. So I want to take the "params object[] args" and get a Type[] of all of those.

Comment: Are you using DynamicInvoke? And I'm not sure how knowing the types would help since the you still need to decide between the ambiguous methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have linq available you can easily get an array of types that matches the objects but I'm not exactly sure it will help in your end goal.

```
var types = args.Select(arg => arg.GetType()).ToArray();
```

Is it your intention to inspect the object array for types and then inspect the method signature and try to match them up appropriately?

Comment: @CodeInChaos true...but his other code that does the dynamic invoking would not work either...

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
        IList<Type> typeList = new List<Type>();

        foreach(object item in args)
        {
            typeList.Add(item.GetType());
        }

        typeList.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the [Array.ConvertAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53.aspx) function a shot:

```
Type[] objTypes = Array.ConvertAll<object, Type>(
    objArray,
    delegate(object obj){
        if(obj==null) return null;
        return obj.GetType();
    });
```